# Unable to install ubuntu 16.04 server edition

Tags: grub2, partitioning, raid

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 server with RAID 1 software configuration.
After the disk partition is done, I'm getting the following error:

```
Executing "grub-install /sdev/sda" failed. This is a fatal error
```

I'm using 2 1TB HDD and installing OS using bootable USB drive